# Create utility like Linux "df", based on source code of this utility

Tags: c++, c, linux

In university a have task - find source code of utility `df`, and using it code - create my own simple utility like `df`. 
But then I simply tried to compile source code of it (file df.c) from (for ex) [this site](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c#ncolumns) - gcc compilation has errors with library and a lot of other errors..
On first step - when I do:

```
gcc -o df.out df.c
```

I have this error:

```
df.c:21:20: fatal error: config.h: no such file.
```

But in /usr/lib folders in my pc there is this file. What's wrong? Or what is another way to create my own `df` utility?

Comment: You're not supposed to compile df.c by itself, It's part of a larger project you'll have to set up & compile.

Comment: Use the build system. Type `./configure && make && sudo make install` to compile and install

Comment: Compiling the original `df` isn't strictly necessary, unless your goal is to add `printf` statements to better understand its flow when it runs.  `df` calls  a handful of library calls (such as `stat` or `statfs` or similar) to do its job.  Without compiling `df`, you should be able to find these and replicate what `df` does in your own program.

Comment: I'm assuming, of course, your university assignment doesn't require you to cover all the options and corner conditions the full-blown `df` utility covers.  It has a lot of code in there that isn't directly related to finding out how much disk space is available.

Comment: @JoeZ, problem to me is to understand what are doing in code of df.c, because there are using SUCH lots of constants, functions and 'define' variables from many headers. And what's why i have problems to write my own df =\

Comment: @hek2mgl, how can i do "./configure" ? i must write some config file?

Comment: You probably need to get the whole `coreutils` source tree and build from that.

Comment: Where did you download the sources?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Answer (score 0):

> problem to me is to understand what are doing in code of df.c, because
>   there are using SUCH lots of constants, functions and 'define'
>   variables from many headers.

The very [site](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c) you mention above has hyperlinks to the definitions everywhere in the code, so you can quickly navigate wherever you need to.